# Удалить из HTML узел с нужным классом

Tags: javascript

Как из куска HTML выцепить и удалить элемент с нужным классом `price priceVariant`? Предполагается что таких блоков `<li>...</li>` много, поэтому использую `querySelectorAll`

```js
        var notAvail = document.querySelectorAll('.globalFrameProduct.not-avail');
        var spanElement = notAvail.querySelectorAll('.price.priceVariant');
        
        for(var i = 0; i < spanElement.length; i++){
            spanElement.parentNode.removeChild(spanElement);
        }
    }
```

```html
<li class="globalFrameProduct not-avail  " data-pos="top" style="">
    <!-- Start. Photo & Name product -->
    <a href="https://........." class="frame-photo-title" title="Сплит система Royal Clima">
        <span class="title">Сплит система Royal Clima CO-F36HN/CO-E36HN</span>
        <span class="photo-block">
            <span class="helper"></span>
            <img src="https://..../uploads/shop/products/medium/3281c909-6af5-11e8-9976-ac220bccaa05_1b566584-6afa-11e8-9976-ac220bccaa05.jpeg" alt="" class="vImg">
                <div class="module_stock"></div>
            </span>
        </a>
        <!-- End. Photo & Name product -->
        <div class="description">
            <!-- Start. article & variant name & brand name -->
            <div class="dop_info_box">
                <table class="dop_info">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Производитель</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="https://..../shop/brand/royal-clima">
                                    Royal Clima
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Серия</td>
                            <td>CO-F-HN</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Наличие</td>
                            <td>в наличии</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Гарантия</td>
                            <td>3 года</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Артикул:</td>
                            <td>
                                ....
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="frame-variant-name-code"></div>
            <!-- End. article & variant name & brand name -->
            <!--
                          -->
            <!-- Start. Prices-->
                <div class="frame-prices f-s_0">
                <!-- Start. Product price-->
                    <span class="current-prices f-s_0"> <span class="price-new"> <span><span class="price priceVariant"> 80 180
                            </span><span class="curr"> руб
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </span>
                <!-- End. Product price-->
            </div>
            <!-- End. Prices-->
            <div class="funcs-buttons frame-without-top">
                <!-- Start. Collect information about Variants, for future processing -->
                <div class="js-variant-35372 js-variant">
                    <div class="alert-exists">Нет в наличии</div>
                    <div class="btn-not-avail">
                        <button class="infoBut isDrop" type="button" data-drop=".drop-report" data-source="/shop/ajax/getNotifyingRequest" data-id="35372" data-product-id="34483" data-name="..." data-vname="" data-number="15407" data-price="80180" data-add-price="" data-orig-price="" data-medium-image="
                                https://..../uploads/shop/products/medium/3281c909-6af5-11e8-9976-ac220bccaa05_1b566584-6afa-11e8-9976-ac220bccaa05.jpeg                " data-img="
                                https://..../uploads/shop/products/small/3281c909-6af5-11e8-9976-ac220bccaa05_1b566584-6afa-11e8-9976-ac220bccaa05.jpeg                " data-maxcount="0" data-url="https://..../shop/product/split-sistema-royal-clima-co-f36hn-co-e36hn"></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End. Collect information about Variants, for future processing -->
            <div class="frame-without-top">
                <!-- Wish List & Compare List buttons -->
                <div class="frame-wish-compare-list  t-a_j">
                    <div class="frame-btn-comp">
                        <!-- Start. Compare List button -->
                        <div class="btn-compare">
                            <div class="toCompare btnCompare" data-id="34483" type="button" data-title="Сравнить" data-firtitle="Сравнить" data-sectitle="В сравнении" data-rel="tooltip">
                                <span class="niceCheck nstcheck">
                                    <input type="checkbox"></span>
                                    <span class="text-el d_l">Сравнить</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- End. Compare List button -->
                        </div>
                    <!---->
                        <!-- Start. Wish list buttons 
        <div class="frame-btn-wish js-variant-35372 js-variant d_i-b_" >
        <div class="btnWish btn-wish " data-id="35372">
    <button 
        class="toWishlist"
        type="button"
        data-rel="tooltip"
        data-title="В избранные"

                    data-drop="#wishListPopup"
            data-source="https://..../wishlist/renderPopup/35372"
                        >
        <span class="icon_wish"></span>
        <span class="text-el d_l">В избранные</span>
    </button>
    <button class="inWishlist" type="button" data-rel="tooltip" data-title="В избранныx" style="display: none;">
        <span class="icon_wish"></span>
        <span class="text-el d_l">В избранныx</span>
    </button>
</div>
<script>
langs["Create list"] = 'Create list';
langs["Wrong list name"] = 'Wrong list name';
langs["Already in Wish List"] = 'Already in Wish List';
langs["List does not chosen"] = 'List does not chosen';
langs["Limit of Wish List finished "] = 'Limit of Wish List finished ';
</script>    </div>
         End. wish list buttons -->
                        <!---->
                    </div>
                    <!-- End. Wish List & Compare List buttons -->
                </div>
                <!-- End. Collect information about Variants, for future processing -->
                <div class="frame-without-top"><!--Start. Description-->
                    <!--        <div class="short-desc">
            Уважаемые покупатели!...        </div>
        -->
                    <!-- End. Description-->
                </div>
            </div>
        <!-- Start. Remove buttons if compare-->
            <!-- End. Remove buttons if compare-->
            <!-- Start. For wishlist page-->
            <!-- End. For wishlist page-->
            <!--<div class="decor-element"></div>-->
        </li>
```

Comment: у вас пример крашится

Comment: removeChild(f) - f - что означает? g - это глобал?

Comment: var myNode = document.getElementsByClassName("foo");
while (myNode.firstChild) {
    myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild);
}

Comment: это анонимная функция где  g  текущий элемент  и массива который вы получили отобрав по имени класса  мой косяк надо  f на g заменить

Comment: var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
 Array.from(elements).forEach(g => document.removeChild(g));  обновил коммент не верно написал

Comment: Этот пример не будет работать так как он ищет по всей странице. По условию только в блоках с классом .globalFrameProduct.not-avail

Comment: не проблема замените document на элемент с классом который вам надо

Comment: почему удалять элементы??

Comment: Если в теге прописано "нет в наличии", то нужно удалить элемент с ценой

Comment: может просто через css display none и все пользователю ваще нет разницы

Comment: нет, надо только JS

Comment: ну так это и будет js вы просто к элементку добавите класс у которого уже заранее стили прописаны  element.classList.add('hide')

Comment: спасибо, я посмотрю как это делается и попробую